# How to pass current table row and JavaScript prompt values to PHP/MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I have a table (several rows, 3 columns) with one column as text, one column as "Delete" link and one column as "Rename" link. Something like this:

1. Hickery dicker dock, the mouse ran up the clock  |  Delete |  Rename

   ---
2. Rudolf the reinderr.........blah blah blah.................|  Delete |  Rename

   ---
3. Hickery dicker dock, the mouse ran up the clock  |  Delete |  Rename

   ---
4. Rudolf the reinderr.........blah blah blah.................|  Delete |  Rename

   ---

If the user clicks "Delete", I was able to delete that particular row from the result set using the following PHP code:

```
echo '<td><a href="delete.php?id='.mysql_result($result, $i, 'code_id').'">Delete</a></td>';
```

However, I want to pass both the row id and the new/renamed text from a JavaScript prompt box to the "rename.php" page, when the user clicks the "Rename" link. I have the following JavaScript code for the Prompt, but I am unable to figure how do I pass both the values (renamed text **+** the selected row id) to the PHP code.

JavaScript for getting the new text using Prompt:

```
function renameTitle(){
            var rename=prompt("Enter new title:");
            if (rename!=null && rename!="") {
                $.post("rename.php", { rename: rename});
            }
        }
```

PHP (rename.php):

```
   echo '<td><a onclick="javascript:renameTitle();" 
href="rename.php?id='
.mysql_result($result, $i, 'code_id')
.'&rename=.....something here.....">Rename</a></td>';
```

I found this somewhat relevant answer, but I need to pass both the values to PHP, instead of just the value in the Prompt box or just the row id.

[Saving javascript prompt() to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734282/saving-javascript-prompt-to-mysql#)

Other ways of doing this using jQuery/JavaScript/PHP are welcome.

Comment: can you give an example please. I thought I was using AJAX by just using ".post" in jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making two requests to `rename.php`. First the Ajax request with `jQuery.post()` with only the `rename` value, then you're redirecting the page with the `id` as `GET` parameter.

These two pieces of data never get together, as the requests are completely separate.

You need to pass both values in one request.

One way you could do it is to pass the `id` as a parameter to your `renameTitle` function and send both in `$.post`:

The JavaScript function:

```
function renameTitle(id){
  var rename=prompt("Enter new title:");
    if (rename!=null && rename!="") {
      $.post("rename.php", { id: id, rename: rename });
    }
}
```

PHP bit:

```
echo '<td><a onclick="javascript:renameTitle(' .
  mysql_result($result, $i, 'code_id') .
  ');" href="">Rename</a></td>';
```

**Note**: The `mysql` extension is deprecated, so you should use `mysqli` instead or switch to PDO.

Comment: Hi Harris, this is great! I really appreciate your help. I was able to get both the values inside the "renameTitle" function. Tested it using console.log(). However, for some reason the ".post" is not doing anything/not responding. Do you have suggestions or any idea what can be wrong?

Comment: If you want `$.post` to do something after the request, you're going to have add a callback function to it by appending `.done()`, for example, to it. You should check out the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) for more examples.

Comment: And if your problem is that `rename.php` is not saving the data, you should of course make sure it's processing the `POST` data properly (using `$_POST['id']` and not `$_GET['id']` etc.)